# Git says Automatic merge failed but when i check the file or run the mergetool there are no conflicts they were resolved correctly

Tags: git, version-control, merge, versioning

As stated in the description.  I would like to not even be prompted to resolve merge conflicts when they were automatically resolved.

My Scenario is that I add a line containing a fixed text string to a text file on one branch, do some other commits on that same branch, then on another branch cherry-pick the change which adds the fixed text, then do a merge with the other branch.

I'm doing this as a test because in my day-to-day i often get conflicts but when i use my merge tool it says there are no conflicts so i just close it and commit manually.

The issue is that i'm prompted for extra steps when in reality git already merged in the changes correctly. (I even checked the file manually to make sure it wasn't my merge tool doing the resolution and indeed the conflict is already resolved int the file).

I tried using the "--commit" parameter to git merge but it has no effect.

It seems like git fails in automatically merging the changes according to the message but in reality it actually merged the files correctly.

Is there a way to just auto merge these kinds of conflicts and continue without manual intervention?

I'm using git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1

Comment: I faced this type of issue when the conflicts were only on white spaces. My mergetool (meld) solved automatically those types of conflicts. Are you sure you are not in this case ? Before calling the mergetool, edit the file and look for <<<<<, =====, and >>>>> markers.

Comment: I don't think so my file contents are as follows:<<<<<<< HEAD
123
=======
12345
>>>>>>> master
new line

Comment: I guess it's conflicting on the first line that it should have auto merged.  I guess that's the problem.  I will do some more testing.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I wonder if i can attach the repository here

Comment: ok here is the situation: branch A and branch B are both based off of the same commit int the past.  On A a new commit adds "new line" on the second line of a file (this was cherry picked from B), On B a commit adds the same "new line" on the second line of the file, then the next commit on B changes "123" to "12345" from the first line.  Note both A and B were based on a commit where "123" was the first line of the file. Now when i merge from B i get the diff i showed above which should have auto-merged. So it looks like git merge fails when it shouldn't nobody modified line one on A

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question, but if you know what you are merging, you can make it so that you don't need to resolve conflicts at all, depending on what you are merging, by giving it a strategy (and options). Non fast forward merges are usually done by the recursive strategy, which is good, but you can give it an option too.

If you merge using

```
$ git merge branchB --strategy=recursive -Xours
```

Then every conflict you would have normally, is instead automatically resolved with your lines. This would probably work in your situation, when you know you shouldn't be getting conflicts, but are getting them anyway. Like I said, this automatically resolves conflicts with your version, so use it only when you know in advance that your version is what is needed.

A more safe option that automatically fixes any conflicts relating to whitespace is `ignore-all-space`. So:

```
$ git merge branchB --strategy=recursive -Xignore-all-space
```

I recommend this one, because it is very safe, it may help your case, and it saves a lot of cases where the to-be-merged file has the entire contents split to local and remote, which would make resolving conflicts very difficult.